# Как можно добраться до атрибутов файла?

Tags: c++

Пишу на С++, mvs 2008. Например у музыки атрибуты исполнитель, год, альбом итд итп. Как я к ним могу обратиться, изменить, сохранить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не атрибуты файла (как readonly, hidden, system...), а тэги, которые вшиты внутри. Чтобы до них добраться - нужно или самому парсить (разбирать и анализировать) содержимое файла, согласно документации на формат файла. Или использовать соответствующие библиотеки. Учитывая, что Explorer.exe также умеет вытаскивать тэги, то возможно использование стандартных виндовых библиотек.

Refs:

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743061(v=vs.85).aspx)

[Wiki: ID3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3)